# Named container shared between different docker-compose files

Tags: docker, docker-compose, volumes

I've seen some similar questions but found no solution for myself.

I have 2 docker-compose files, I have created a named volume and I'm currently using it like this:

```
app:
    ...
    volumes:
      - volume_static:/path/to/container
    ...
...
volumes:
  ...
  volume_static:
    external:
      name: static
  ...
...
```

During the build process, it happens that the script adds some new file to this volume, but then, the second docker-compose, which mount the volume in the exact same manner, have no access to the new data, I need to restart it to make it work.

Is this the right approach?

I just need to push some new file in the volume from one docker-compose, and see them directly on the second docker-compose (yeah I know, docker, but saying specifying compose give a better idea on what is my problem) without restarting and building the service

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker believes named volumes are there to hold user data, and other things that aren't part of the normal container lifecycle.

If you start a container with an empty volume, only the very first time you run it, Docker will load content from the image into the volume.  Docker does not have an update mechanism for this: since the volume presumably holds user data, Docker can't risk corrupting it by overwriting files with content from the updated image.

The best approach here is to avoid sharing files at all.  If the files are something like static assets for a backend application, you can [`COPY --from`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy) those files from the backend image into a proxy image, using the image name and tag of your backend application (`COPY --from=my/backend ...`).  That avoids the need for the volume altogether.

If you really must share files in a volume, then the container providing the files needs to take responsibility for copying in the files itself when it starts up.  An entrypoint script is the easiest place to do this; it gives you a hook to run things as the container starts (and volumes exist and are mounted) but before running the main container process.

```sh
#!/bin/sh
set -e

# Populate (or update) the shared static tree
cp -r ./app/assets /static

# Now run the image CMD
exec "$@"
```

Make this script be the `ENTRYPOINT` in your Dockerfile; it must use the JSON-array syntax.  You can leave your `CMD` unchanged.  If you've split an interpreter and filename into separate `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` you can combine those into a single `CMD` line (and probably should anyways).

```
...
ENTRYPOINT ["entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

In terms of build lifecycle, images are built without any of the surrounding Compose ecosystem; they are not aware of the network environment, volumes, environment variables, bind mounts, *etc.*; so when you rebuild the image you build a new changed image but don't modify the volume at all.  The very first time you run the whole file, since the named volume is empty, it is populated with content from the volume, but this only happens the very first time you run it.

Rebuilding images and restarting containers is extremely routine in Docker and I wouldn't try to avoid that.  (It's so routine that re-running `docker-compose up -d` will delete and recreate an existing container if it needs to in order to change settings.)